# Backbone => React - Higher Order Components, inheritance and specialisation

Tags: reactjs, inheritance, backbone.js, composition, higher-order-components

I have a legacy Backbone app which I have begun to rewrite in React. The app has a main view containing two subviews, arranged vetically. The top panel displays some data, and the bottom one displays the result of some algorithm taking this data as input. Since I have many different data sources, each with a different algorithm applied to it, I have an abstract base View class, which I then subclass for each data source, adding, decorating and overriding methods as necessary. Somewhat like this:

```
// Base View.
const BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {},

  initialize() {
    this.subViewA = // instantiate subview...
    this.subViewB = // instantiate subview...
  },

  generateResultData() {
    // 'Abstract' method which should be specialised to generate data rendered by subViewB...
  },

  render() {
    // render subviews...
  },

});

// Derived View.
const Derived = BaseView.extend({

  events: {
    // event handlers...
  },

  add(a, b) {
    return a+b;
  },

  // additional methods...

  generateResultData() {
    return {
      result: this.add(2,2);
    }
  },

})
```

This results in a shallow hierarchy of many similar View classes. It's all terribly imperative, but it's a simple, intuitive and easy-to-reason-about pattern, and just *works*. I'm struggling to see how to achieve the same thing in React, however. Given that subclassing of subclasses of `React.Component` is considered an anti-pattern, my focus has naturally been on composition, and in particular Higher Order Components. HOCs (which I find beautiful, but unintuitive and often just downright confusing) seem to involve adding general features, rather than specialising/refining something more general. I have also considered passing in more specialised versions of Componenet methods through props. but that just means I have to use the same boilerplate Component definition over and over again:

```
// General functional component, renders the result of prop function 'foo'.
function GeneralComponent(props) {
  const foo = this.props.foo || ()=>"foo";
  return (
    <div>
      <span> { this.props.foo() } </span>
    </div>
  )
}

// Specialised component 1, overrides 'foo'.
class MySpecialisedComponent extends React.Component {
  foo() {
    return this.bar()
  }

  bar() {
    return "bar"
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GeneralComponent foo={this.foo} />
    )
  }
}

// Specialised component 2, overrides 'foo' and adds another method.
class MyOtherSpecialisedComponent extends React.Component {
  foo() {
    return this.bar() + this.bar()
  }

  bar() {
    return "bar"
  }

  baz() {
    return "baz"
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GeneralComponent foo={this.foo} />
    )
  }
}
```

The above is a very simplistic case, obviously, but essentially captures what I need to do (though I would of course be manipulating state, which the example does not do, for simplicity). I mean, I *could* just do things like that. But I want to avoid having to repeat that boilerplate all over the place. So is there a simpler and more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: The problem with these classes is that they don't benefit from being classes, they act as namespaces and may be unjustified. A more concrete example would help to understand your case better. Foos and bars explain what you're doing but not how this could be improved.

Comment: @estus Indeed. I've added something a bit more concrete, for the Backbone case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO what is throwing you off isn't inheritance vs composition, it's your data flow:

> For example, many of my derived views need to do custom rendering after the main render. I'm using a third-party SVG library, and the data rendered into the 'result' subview is derived from analysis of rendered SVG elements in the main data view above it

So what you're trying to do here is have a child update props of a distantly related component after render, correct? Like this?

```
// after the svg renders, parse it to get data
<div id="svg-container">
  <svg data="foo" />
  <svg data="bar />
</div>

// show parsed data from svg after you put it through your algos
<div id="result-container">
  // data...
</div>
```

There's a lot of state management libraries out there that will help you with this problem, that is, generating data in one component and broadcasting it to a distantly related component. If you want to use a tool built-in to react to address this you may want to use [`context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), which gives you a global store that you can provide to any component that wants to consume it.

In your example your child classes have data-specific methods (`add`, etc.). IMO it's more typical in react to have a generic class for displaying data and simply passing it down map functions as props in order to rearrange/transform the rendered data.

```
class AbstractDataMap extends PureComponent {
  static defaultProps = {
    data: [],
    map: (obj, i) => (<div key={i}>{obj}</div>)
  };

  render() {
    const { data, map, children } = this.props;
    const mapped = data.map(map);

    return (
      <Fragment>
        {mapped.map((obj, i) => (
          children(obj, i)
        ))}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

// in some other container
class View extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AbstractDataMap data={[1, 2, 3]} map={(n) => ({ a: n, b: n + 1 })}>
          {({ a, b }, i) => (<div key={i}>a: {a}, b: {b}</div>)}
        </AbstractDataMap>

        <AbstractDataMap data={[2, 4, 6]} map={(n) => (Math.pow(n, 2))}>
          {(squared, i) => (<div key={i}>squared: {squared}</div>)}
        </AbstractDataMap>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

IMO this pattern of using an HOC to abstract away the labor of explicitly using `.map` in your render calls (among other uses) is the pattern you are looking for. However, as I stated above, the HOC pattern has nothing to do your main issue of shared data store across sibling components.

Comment: Thank you so much for that. Sorry for the delay in responding. In fact I had begun using MongoDB's [connect-backbone-to-react](https://github.com/mongodb-js/connect-backbone-to-react) library, which allowed me to pass down my Backbone models through the app. But see my own answer to the question, which explains a bit more about the approach I decided to adopt.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if a component is stateless and doesn't use lifecycle hooks, there are no reasons for it to be `Component` class. A class that acts as a namespace and doesn't hold state can be considered an antipattern in JavaScript.

In constrast to some other frameworks, React doesn't have templates that would need to map variables in order for them to be available in view, so the only place where `bar` function needs to be mentioned is the place where it's called. JSX is an extension over JavaScript, JSX expressions can use any names that are available in current scope. This allows to compose functions without any classes:

```
const getBar => "bar";
const getBaz => "baz";
const getBarBaz => getBar() + getBaz();

const MySpecialisedComponent = props => <GeneralComponent foo={getBar} />;
const MyOtherSpecialisedComponent = props => <GeneralComponent foo={getBarBaz} />;
```

An anonymous function could be passed as `foo` prop instead of creating `getBarBaz` but this is generally discouraged because of unnecessary overhead.

Also, default prop values could be assigned with [`defaultProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values) without creating new `()=>"foo"` function on each component call:

```
function GeneralComponent({ foo }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <span> {foo()} </span>
    </div>
  )
}

GeneralComponent.defaultProps = { foo: () => 'foo' };
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was explained very clearly. Unfortunately my example may have been rather misleading, as the actual scenario is much more complex. For example, many of my derived views need to do custom rendering after the main render. I'm using a third-party SVG library, and the data rendered into the 'result' subview is derived from analysis of rendered SVG elements in the main data view above it - lengths, ratios, intersections, etc. So it's a bit complicated. I think in principle it is still amenable to a composition-based approach, however.

Comment: I'd expect that the scenario will require container component to be a class, looks like the analysis should be performed in componentDidMount/componentDidUpdate hooks and then results are passed as props to subview components. Still, this can be done in various ways, it's unnecessary that it will need inheritance. If you have more specific example how it works, consider adding it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, which I've never donw before...

So my question really arose from a concern that I would need to refactor a large, imperative and stateful codebase so as to integrate with React’s composition-based model (also with Redux). But it occurred to me after reading the (very insightful and helpful) responses to my question that my app has two parallel parts: the UI, and an engine which runs the algorithms (actually it's a music analysis engine). And I can strip out the Backbone View layer to which the engine is connected quite easily. So, using React’s [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) API I've built an ‘AnalysisEngineProvider', which makes the engine available to subcomponents. The engine is all very imperative and classically object-oriented, and still uses Backbone models, but that makes no difference to the UI as the latter has no knowledge of its internals - which is how it should be (the models will likely be refactored out at some point too)...

The engine also has responsibility for rendering the SVG (not with BB views). But React doesn’t know anything about that. It just sees an empty div. I take a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) from the div and pass it to the engine so the latter knows where to render. Beyond that the engine and the UI have little contact - the divs are never updated from React state changes at all (other components of the UI are though, obviously). The models in the engine only ever trigger updates to the SVG, which React knows nothing about.

I am satisfied with this approach, at least for now - even if it's only part of an incremental refactor towards a fully React solution. It feels like the right design for the app whatever framework I happened to be using.